# How do I write a regular expression that matches strings with exactly one space between each word and no trailing or leading spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

**Single regx for all these Conditions**
1.Should allow only aphanumeric
2. along with only one space between words
3. Should allow only special characters like -.,'
4. Should not allow leading space, trailing space and consecutive blank space.

Valid input:

```
"testing with 2 regx solution"
```

Invalid input:

```
" testing    with 2 regx solution" or "testing  %^with 2 regx solution "
```

Comment: I'm sure you tried something, right?

Comment: When creating new Regex patterns I reference two items: 1) http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet, and 2) A program called Expresso. This one is a fairly simple one. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
^(\w+\s)*\w+$
```

> ```
> ^     Start of string
> (     Start of group
> \w+   Word of one or more characters
> \s    White space
> )     End of group
> *     Zero or more of the preeceding group
> \w+   Word of one or more characters
> $     End of string
> ```

Comment: Actually, your regex will not match `abc` (a sole word). Not sure if it is a requirement of the questioner though - he does not explicitly mention this case - the question sounds like the regex need to match a sole word for me :)

Comment: @luiges90 Changed the `+` to a `*` for the group quantifier to allow matching of a sole word, as I agree it may be needed. They are interchangeable depending on the requirements of the original poster.

Answer (score -1):

```
 inputString= Regex.Replace(inputString.Trim(),@"\s+"," ");
```

--SJ

Comment: The question asks how to match "strings with exactly one space between each word and no trailing or leading spaces" not modify strings to meet those criteria.