# Regular expression that matches strings with exactly one space between each word and no trailing or leading spaces

Tags: .net, regex

How do I write a regular expression that matches strings with exactly one space between each word and no trailing or leading spaces? The string can - apart from letters - contain only [-.,'] characters and no consecutive spaces between words.

- Valid : `"testing 2 regx-tested"`
- Invalid: `"testing  regx#tested "`

Comment: Empty string should be valid otr not?

Comment: Could u atleast add a question to your assignment?.. We are here to help, people with things they can't figure out themselves. You are simply tossing in a requirement. What have you tried yourself? I am not going to bother completing your assignment for you. People usually pay me for that.

Comment: It seems you asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745460/how-do-i-write-a-regular-expression-that-matches-strings-with-exactly-one-space?rq=1) before and it was closed. The link shows up in the 'Related' part.

Comment: Instead of creating a new question when your old is closed (this behaviour will more than likely lead to you automatically being banned from asking questions), edit your old one with any new details, what you've tried, where you're having issues. As it stands, this question contributes absolutely zilch to the Stack Overflow community.

Answer (score 0):

Just write down what you said

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[-0-9a-z.,']+( [-0-9a-z.,']+)*");
```

that should match a word and then many other words separated by a single space.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but it's not working for me. Should not allow consecutive space between words and should allow numeric.

Comment: This regx allowing blank space at beginning and end of the string and also allows consecutive blank space between words.

Comment: You need to match it against the whole string, not just part of it. I'm sure you can fix that on your own :)